# How to bind property of a given item in a collection?

Tags: ember.js

I have a list of videos inside a Ember.ArrayController that I render on my view using the {{each}} helper like this, video object has an url property :

```
  {{#each App.videosController}}
              <li>{{url}}</li>
              {{#view Em.Button action="play" target="App.videoPlayer"}}Play{{/view}}
   {{/each}}
```

I also have a play button for each video. I'd like this button to call play method of my video player and give the url of the selected item. Here is my video player :

```
App.videoPlayer = Em.Object.create({

    url: null,

    play: function(e){
        this.set('url',e.context); // it doesn't work'!!!
    }

});
```

How can I send the url to my player when I click on the button ? I can't figure out how to do this.

Answer (score 3):

Something along the lines of this should work:

```
  {{#each App.videosController}}
              <li>{{url}}</li>
              {{#view Em.Button contentBinding="this" action="play" target="App.videoPlayer"}}Play{{/view}}
   {{/each}}

App.videoPlayer = Em.Object.create({
    content: null,
    url: null,

    play: function(e){
        var itemUrl = Ember.getPath(this, 'content.url');
        Ember.set(this, 'url', itemUrl);
    }

});
```

The important part is: `contentBinding="this"`. That sends the content of the singular item in your collection to your view for use.

Comment: Thanks. It works now, I only change Ember.getPath(this, ...) by Ember.getPath(e,...)